# Aws MediaConvert - Create multiples outputs video HLS and audios with a single video mp4

Tags: amazon-web-services, hls.js, aws-media-convert

I want to create a job in AWS MediaConvert to convert a video mp4 to a output group Apple HLS with the different qualities of the video, for example 1080p, 720p and 480p, and 2 audios tracks (stereo and no-voices stereo).
I create 3 outputs of video (1080p, 720p and 480p associated by the "audio rendering sets" config with the other 2 outputs audios (stereo, no-stereo).

Thats the correct way to generate a video adaptative with multiple audios?

Can i mute the audio in no voices stereo from the input file (mp4)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question to be:  can you mute audio sources from the input files?

Answer:  yes.  You can either [a] not select that audio track for your job, so it will not be used at all;  or [b] you can greatly reduce the gain on any audio track using the 'Input remix controls'.  This will retain the track but make it functionally silent.

For HLS outputs, you have at least two options for including audio:

[a] audio content can be embedded in the video segments by adding the audio element to the Output which describes the video rendition. This is the default behavior for the first audio selector.

Or [b] you can have the audio tracks be separate HLS outputs (separate child manifests and segments). This is achieved by adding another Output to the HLS output group, and removing the video element from the audio-only output.

If you method [b], remember to set an 'Audio Group ID' for each discrete audio rendition,  and remember to associate those Audio Group IDs with the Video rendition(s) by providing the names of the Audio Group IDs in the Video output configuration in 'Audio rendition sets' field.  This field tells MediaConvert which audio renditions(s) should be included in the #EXT-X-STREAM-INF video lines of the manifest by including the ,AUDIO="Audio Group ID" parameter.

Comment: Yeah, but my input files is a mp4, and i want to separate the voices of the person talking but no the music audio. Is that possible? And how can i dont select the audio track? i put only 1 audio selector in inputs. And this "you can greatly reduce the gain on any audio track using the 'Input remix controls'. This will retain the track but make it functionally silent." is in output audio or input?

Comment: The HLS output group will need three renditions:  once video-only, one audio for 'voices-stereo' and one audio for 'no_voices_stereo'.

 Name each audio rendition with a unique Audio group ID.


On the video rendition, put both audio rendition names in the 'Audio rendition sets' field  so the manifest will list both audio options with your video track.